# How can I assign keyboard shortcuts in Visual Studio without using the GUI?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

How can I assign keyboard shortcuts in Visual Studio without using the GUI (Tools / Options / Environment / Keyboard)? I would like to be able to script or otherwise automate these changes somehow. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried editing the file and or registry key that stores the shortcuts themselves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My install seems a bit messed up so it's not clear if editing the currentsettings.vssettings and reloading Visual Studio is enough, but Exporting and Importing at the very worst should work. I didn't realize this was stored in XML anywhere. I think it all used to be hopelessly binary. Thanks to Ramhound for pointing me in the right direction! This is a good case of what happens when you start with assumptions.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13503447/visual-studio-key-bindings-configuration-file

Also worth noting is that the location of your currentsettings.vssettings file can be found under Tools / Import and Export Settings.